# Html entities in file names: Possible mine traps?

Tags: image, filesystems

When I thought about resizing images and saving the new sizes parallel on the server, I came to the following question:

```
// Original size
DSC_18342.jpg

// New size: Use an "x" for "times"
DSC_18342_640x480px.jpg

// New size: Use the real "×" for "times"
DSC_18342_640×480px.jpg
```

The point is, that it's *slightly* easier if you got a real `×` instead of an `x` in the file name, as the unit `px` already contains the `x`, which makes it a little bit harder to read.

> **Question:** What problems could I get in, when using the Html entity in the filename?

*Sidenotes:* I'm writing an open source, publicly available script, so the targeted server can be *anything* - therefore I'm also interested (and will vote up) edge cases, that I'm not aware off.

Thank you all!

---

You may have noticed, that I'm aware, that I could simply avoid it (which I'll do anyway), but I'm interested in this issue and learning about it, so please just take above example as *possible case*.

Comment: I'd imagine the biggest problem is that it's really hard for a human to type.

Comment: I think you mean Unicode characters, not html entities. I'm sure it's not a bad idea, different file systems already cause enough problems because of uppercase/lowercase handling. Why don't you just omit the `px` - do you ever use any other units?

Comment: I dunno, apostrophes are pretty easy for humans to type, as is ampersand. And a lot of the international characters are easy to type for the users who actually use those languages. I don't see what relevance a character having an HTML entity reference has on whether it should be used in a filename.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: I'm not sure many keyboards have a real multiplication character on them...

Comment: @Oli: That has nothing to do with HTML character entities. There are characters which don't have named entities in HTML which aren't commonly found on keyboards. Just like there are many characters with named entities which _are_ commonly found on keyboards.

Comment: Oh, that second sentence should read: I'm sure it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: I realise that it's nothing to do with HTML entities; my initial comment was a response to the OP's specific example.

Comment: @kapep Yes, I mean Unicode/UTF-8 characters that are **not found** on _common_ keyboards. At all) I wrote that its not about that I need it, not even about that ↑ specific case (which is just an example). I'm _just interested_ in what problems/edge cases there are, that _would_ need to be considered. To say it again: The _fictional_ example is just there to _illustrate_ what I'm after. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are file systems that simply don't support unicode. This may be less of a problem if you make unicode support a requirement of your application.

Some consideration about different unicode file system are given in [File Systems, Unicode, and Normalization](http://developers.sun.com/global/products_platforms/solaris/reference/presentations/IUC29-FileSystems.pdf).

A concluding remark (from a viewpoint of solaris file systems) is:

> Complete compatibility and seamless interoperability with
>   all other existing Unicode file systems appears not 100%
>   possible due to inherent differences.

I can imagine that there will be problems especially when migrating the application. Just storing files is probably no problem but if their names are stored in a database there might be a mismatch after migration.